# 'publish actions' permission is not require for screenshot posting?

Tags: facebook, permissions, unity-game-engine, review

Sorry. I can not speak English well.

I'm developing a small game using UNITY3D and Facebook UNITY SDK

I have submitted a review to facebook team for publish_actions permission.

(My game post a screenshot to user's timeline.)

And I received this result message .

> "Your app experience does not need the requested permission."

I'm using Facebook SDK example code for screenshot function.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() 
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");

    FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
}
```

'Screenshot button' is pressed, dialog does not appear. 
when I tried screenshot function without permission, this function did not working

What's wrong?

Comment: "Your app experience does not need the requested permission." <-- does this refer to the FB team simply not being able to execute your take screenshot action? Shouldn't your question really be asking: "why does the take screenshot dialog not appear"? It's confusing because initially it seems to be about the FB Team's result.

Comment: Dialogue is not require. 
I asked this problem to facebook dev group and I got this answer.
"Hey! How are you using publish actions? Are you using a share dialog or other plugin? If you are you don't need publish actions."

Answer (score 1):

The docs at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#pubperms

clearly state that you need the `publish_actions` permission to be able to upload photos for the User.